# RegeX to validate Email OR Phone No. OR URL

Tags: javascript, regex

HI Would like to ask if its possible to create a RegEx like this
var regex = (Valid Email)|(Any Number 1 to 15 Digits)|(URL with Protool(https|https) and without (www.google.com)))

```
Valid
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
sample.s.sample@gmail.com
sample.s@gmail.com
1
12
..
15
Invalid
testemailinvalid.test.yahoo2
A
AAAAA
a
aaaaaaaa
sasasa
```

I already have a regex expression regarding this WHEN I put the number validation in the middle the number are not accepted.and when i put it last the email input are not accepted

```
var re =  (/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))+(-(^[0][1-9]+)|([1-9]\d*))|(((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*))$/);
```

Comment: Though I'm not sure it is possible without google.com :)

Comment: can  i do it without negating each one?

Comment: If that's the case, then you have to take care of the TLD as well as you allow URLs without a specified protocol (though its not a good practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recode all of my regex and its now properly working
What i did is add another + sign in the end of the second chunk of expression

```
var re =  (/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))+(-(^[0][1-9]+)|([1-9]\d*))|+(((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*))$/);
```